# Golang (v1.8) - Error: type *mux.Route has no field or method Method

Tags: go, methods, routes, gorilla

I have a go/golang application equipped the gorilla toolkit. I am trying to utilize the gorilla/mux package for routing. My routes and the error message are below. Any pointers?

Routes
   `

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/", landing)
r.HandleFunc("/contact", contact)
r.HandleFunc("/faq", faq)
r.HandleFunc("/register", accountsC.New).Method("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/register", accountsC.Create).Method("POST")
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)`
```

I have received this error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:27: r.HandleFunc("/register", accountsC.New).Method undefined 
(type *mux.Route has no field or method Method)
./main.go:28: r.HandleFunc("/register", accountsC.Create).Method undefined 
(type *mux.Route has no field or method Method)
```

Comment: Looking for `Methods("GET","POST")`? Or maybe you just want `GET` for the one and `POST` for the other. https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.Methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method `Method`, you need to use [`Methods`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.Methods)

Answer (score 0):

There is no method Method, you need to use **Methods**
should be like that

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/", landing)
r.HandleFunc("/contact", contact)
r.HandleFunc("/faq", faq)
r.HandleFunc("/register", accountsC.New).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/register", accountsC.Create).Methods("POST")
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
```